# Angular injection loop

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, dependency-injection

I am having a problem in my AngularJS and I cannot seem to find easy solution out of it. I am using two services for user authorization with the server. The authorisation is based on two tokens: Access token and Refresh token.

Now I have one service (Auth) that takes care of the whole authorisation process and second service (Api) that takes care of communication with the server.

The way the authorisation works is that user accesses data with his Access Token. Once the token is invalitated, it will try to submit refresh token and hopefully get back new access token.

The problem is that if server responds with 401 and the token is invalidated I want to simply run Auth.authenticate(); on the background (no redirects or anything) and if successful continue with the new access token.

Unfortunately since Auth service is using Api service, I cannot inject Auth service back to the Api service. Is there any good way to do what I want to do from one global place (so I don't have to call the re-authorization after every single request in controller)?

Some architectural info:

```
Auth Service (injects Api Service)
| ---- authorisation function (uses Api Service)

Api Service
| ---- Different functions to prepare data for request
| ---- One function to send all requests
| ---- One function to handle all rejected promisses which includes detection of 401 and should include "silent" re-authorisation (AuthService.authorisation)
```

I have tried interceptors, but the outcome is the same - injector loop.

The only idea I have, without changing my architecture, is if there is any way to get current active instance of the Auth service, as it is loaded anyway. But couldn't find any details on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, also with my authorisation.

Sometimes re-architecting is the best solution, but I think in this case you have a good use-case for wanting the 'circular' access you are describing.

Try the following:

1. Inject `$injector` into your API service instead of your Auth service.
2. User `$injector.get('AuthService')` to get the instantiated Auth service.